# Explain why the curve is apart of the tangentplane

Tags: differential-geometry

Let the curve $\gamma:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be given by $\gamma(t)=(t,t^{2},h(t,t^{2})$. Explain why $\gamma'(1)$ is a part $T_{(1,1)}\rho$ and determine $\gamma'(1)$

I have calculated Normal vector to \begin{align}
     N &= \begin{bmatrix}
           4 \\
           -1 \\
           3\\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

I don't understand why $\gamma(t)=(t,t^{2},h(t,t^{2})=\rho(t,t^{2})$ ? secound when I differentiate $\gamma'(1)=(1,2,a)$
that $\gamma$ is an curve on $\rho$ ?
and that belongs to $\gamma'(1)$ tangenplane for $\rho$ in (1,1) and therefore it is perpendicular to N which i don't understand

Comment: My apologies, I am a little confused here. What is $\rho$? Is it some surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: yes it is  in that point where i had to make an equation for the tangent plane for the surface. Andn from that i calculated the gradient and got my normal vector

Comment: Okay, so we are taking $\gamma$ to be a curve contained within the surface described by $\rho$, and we have no equation for $\rho$, but are rather viewing it as any abstract surface containing the curve $\gamma$? Also, when you say $T_{(1,1)}\rho$, did you mean to say $T_{(1,1,h(1,1))}\rho$, or are we taking the pullback of the inclusion map $\iota:\rho\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ here and considering local coordinates on $\rho(u,v)$ where we take $u$ and $v$ to both be 1?

Comment: Oh, wait. I think I finally parsed what this means. Please correct me if I am wrong. What you are saying is that we have a surface $\rho$ given by a function $h(x,y)$, which might be locally parameterized by $(x,y,h(x,y))$. We are then considering the image of the parabola $\gamma(t) = (t,t^2,h(t,t^2))$ contained within this surface, and the question is first of all, to explain why $\gamma'(1)$ is contained within the tangent plane of $\rho$ at the point $(1,1,h(1,1))$ and to determine the formula for $\gamma'(1)$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

First we will explain why $\gamma'(1)\in T_{(1,1,h(1,1))}\rho$. This comes down to definitions. For any surface $\Sigma$, the tangent plane to the surface $\Sigma$ at a point $q$ is defined to be the set of all tangent vectors at that point. Symbolically, this looks like
$$T_q\Sigma = \{\alpha'(t_0)\: \mid \: \alpha(t):I\rightarrow \Sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^3,\: \alpha(t_0) = q\}$$
where $I$ is some interval containing $t_0$ and $\alpha$ is non-singular (no sharp points, and no self intersection) and at least once differentiable. Now, since the surface can be given the paratmeterization $\rho(x,y) = (x,y,h(x,y))$, we can see that the curve $\gamma: (1-\varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3:t\mapsto (t,t^2,h(t,t^2))$ will be completely contained in $\rho$, and that $\gamma'(1) \in T_{(1,1,h(1,1))}\rho$ by definition.

Now to determine $\gamma'(1)$. Since we have parameterized this entire curve in terms of $t$, this is not too bad to do, but we will need to be careful with the last coordinate since it is expressed as a function of two variables. By the multivariate chain rule, we have that
$$\frac{d}{dt}h(x,y) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$
and with our given parameterization of $x(t) = t$, and $y(t) = t^2$ this becomes
$$\frac{d}{dt}h(t,t^2) = 1\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(t,t^2) + 2t\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(t,t^2).$$
The rest is just Calc I, and we compute component-wise
$$\gamma'(t) = \left(1,2t,\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(t,t^2) + 2t\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(t,t^2)\right).$$
So the final answer is
$$\gamma'(1) = \left(1,2,\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(1,1) + 2\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(1,1)\right).$$

As for why this is perpendicular to the normal vector, recall that the normal vector for the surface $\rho(x,y)$ with parameterization $(x,y,h(x,y))$ is given by $\rho_x(x_0,y_0) \times \rho_y(x_0,y_0)$ where the subscripts denote partial derivatives of the coordinate curves $\alpha(x) = (x,y_0,h(x,y_0))$ and $\beta(y) = (x_0,y,h(x_0,y))$ where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are constants. Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$, like $\gamma(t)$, are both contained within the surface $\rho$ and that their cross product is perpendicular to the surface. So if we look at $\rho_x(1,1) \times \rho_y(1,1)$, this vector, which is a multiple of the properly oriented unit normal vector, necessarily has to be perpendicular to the tangent plane at the point $(1,1,h(1,1))$, and we already established that the vector $\gamma'(1)$ was a member of this tangent plane.

Let me know if this explanation helps!